# Should I use MPM prefork or MPM event in apache?

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with apache/2.4.18. I need to know which MPM module should I use whether MPM_prefork (which is default in my case) or MPM_event (which is a newly built module). It must be noted that we are dealing with huge traffic on webserver with configuration of 16-GB RAM and 8-cores CPU.

Answer (score 2):

See [this article](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-apache-web-server-performance/#prefork-mpm) for a good overview of the 3 main MPMs.

My suggestion would be to consider going with **Event MPM** as it should be better at dealing with high loads.